# pyglet - WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet

I am testing pyglet on my laptop using this code:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    print 'A key was pressed'

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python Games\New Game\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    window = pyglet.window.Window()
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\__init__.py", line 357, in __getattr__
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1817, in <module>
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\gl\__init__.py", line 205, in _create_shadow_window
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 131, in __init__
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 559, in __init__
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 263, in _create
  File "_build\bdist.win32\egg\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 203, in attach
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000
[Finished in 2.313s]
```

My laptop is quite old. I am running windows 10;

Comment: Can't reproduce this code on a 4GB machine running Windows 10.
Tried both with either `python 2.7.11`, `python 3.4.3` or `python 3.5.1`. What version of python and pyglet are you using and how much memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 with 2Gb and a pathetic Intel graphics card.

Comment: This _usually_ happens in either two cases. One would be that you actually ran out of memory (2GB isn't that much especially since Windows 10 basic *basic* install requires roughly 1.3GB of RAM on it's own). Or you lack proper drivers for either your graphic card or a GL library (DirectX or OpenGL for instance). Try updating all your drivers, another thing you could do is run a trace on your code and see where it fails. `python -m trace --trace main.py`.